# How to parse sentence that is multilingual?

Tags: stanford-nlp, text-parsing

When I use Stanford Parser to parse sentences like:
"Jirí Hubac 's script is a gem ."
"Absorbing character study by André Turpin ."

It raise internal error.

How to deal with such situation that the sentence is multilingual?

Answer (score 1):

Using the full Stanford CoreNLP toolkit available here:

http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/

I ran this command:

```
java -Xmx6g -cp "stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse -file example.txt -outputFormat text
```

It had no problem parsing your example sentence and the output can be found in the file: example.txt.out

Could you please provide the command you issued and the error you got when trying to run on this sentence?

Comment: @StanfodNLPHelp I use the Python interface provided in the [link](https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python) with just the provided command 'code server.parse('some sentence') ' inline `code in backticks`

Comment: I wouldn't use that Python wrapper.  You could try using the Stanford CoreNLP server: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html and use this Python wrapper: https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp ...though I should note if you just want to process a lot of sentences you could just use the command I provided above in an os.system() call and then process the output...if you use "-outputFormat json" instead of text our toolkit will output json of the processed sentences

Comment: @StanfodNLPHelp This is of great help to me. In addition, how can I obtain the binarized parsing tree from Stanford Parser? Is there any parameters for this? Thank you!

Comment: My understanding is the easiest way to handle this is to use this class: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/tools/ParseAndSetLabels.java ... so you're going to have to get the toolkit from GitHub, build it (there are some instructions on the front page) ... then if you use the main() method of that class it will parse sentences and binarize ... so the yes there is functionality in the toolkit to binarize trees, but you will have to run some Java stuff to achieve that

Comment: Note that the comments at the top for ParseAndSetLabels.java has a sample command for how to run it.  You don't want to use the label replacement part so I suppose give that an empty file and set missing labels to KEEP_ORIGINAL.

Comment: If you get stuck let me know, this should be pretty straightforward though.  You just have to build the full GitHub version of the project, and run that sample command with the right settings and you can get binary trees.

Comment: java edu.stanford.nlp.parser.tools.ParseAndSetLabels -output foo.txt -sentences "C:\Users\JohnBauer\Documents\alphasense\dataset\sentences10.txt" -labels "C:\Users\JohnBauer\Documents\alphasense\dataset\phrases10.tsv" -parser edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz -tagger edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger -remapLabels 0=1,1=2,2=2,3=0,4=0 -binarize  ... this is the sample command I'm referring to

Comment: I perform binarized parsing with POS with command: `java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.tools.ParseAndSetLabels -output foo.txt -sentences example.txt -labels example_label.txt`. But some strange POS in the parsing result, such as tagging "@VP, @S". I also tried the command you provide with `-tagger` used, but there are errors: `Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading$ReflectionLoadingException: Error creating edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger`. The model file I used is **corenlp-2016-01-10-models.jar**. Should I retrain the model?

Comment: How can I set left or right binarization? Are there some parameters?